# Unable to setup MarkLogic spring batch basic app

Tags: java, gradle, spring-batch, marklogic, ml-gradle

I'm trying to setup the sample app to load 100 docs in MarkLogic server using the spring batch git documentation but I get this error everytime I try to run my job:

```
    *** What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':runYourJob'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':testRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not download marklogic-xcc.jar (com.marklogic:marklogic-xcc:9.0.2)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/marklogic/marklogic-xcc/9.0.2/marklogic-xcc-9.0.2.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/libs-release-bintray/com/marklogic/marklogic-xcc/9.0.2/marklogic-xcc-9.0.2.jar?referrer'.
            > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target**
```

The URL for the basic setup is here: https://github.com/marklogic-community/marklogic-spring-batch/wiki/Getting-Started

I'm using IntelliJ as the IDE & also tried to download & add the .jar to the classpath dependency. I'd appreciate any help here. I'm not sur if this could be a gradle issue.

EDIT: This error is common while building any marklogic gradle app & not specific to spring. I'm using MarkLogic 10 & gradle version 5.4.1 on adoptOpenJDK11 in a windows 10 machine.

Answer (score 0):

> Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/marklogic/marklogic-xcc/9.0.2/marklogic-xcc-9.0.2.jar'

The location https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/marklogic/marklogic-xcc/9.0.2/ does not contain the requested jar `marklogic-xcc-9.0.2.jar`. Make sure to point to a valid maven repository containing that jar.

Comment: I'm not pointing to any custom repo. However when I click on the link for the jar it download the jar file in my browser.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of your error is that a dependency is missing in the `build.gradle`.

My Spring framework MVC version is:

```
MarkLogic Java API      5.3.0
JDK                     11
Spring Framework        5.2.7
Spring Batch            4.2.4
```

If you clone the whole project and have not upgraded any dependencies:

1. Add line `24` in the `core:build.gradle`

[image]

2. Load gradle change in `IntelliJ` and clean deploy the project.

Upon the successful gradle build, an App server (in my case, App name is `ml-spring-batch` @ 7010) is scaffolded:

[image]

3. In `IntelliJ`, execute gradle task against `samples` ONLY. In `cmd`, run task: `gradle runYourJob`. Upon the gradle task completion, 100 documents are loaded in the content database.